# UIAlertAction not reusable

Tags: ios, uikit, uialertaction

When trying to reuse `UIAlertAction`, it looks like the handler is being executed only once.
I've created a test project with an array of `UIAlertAction` with 3 actions:

```
private var actions = [UIAlertAction]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    var ac = UIAlertAction(title: "A",
                           style: .default) { (actioni) in
        print("Selected A")
    }
    
    actions.append(ac)
    
    ac = UIAlertAction(title: "B",
                           style: .default) { (actioni) in
        print("Selected B")
    }
    
    actions.append(ac)
    
    ac = UIAlertAction(title: "C",
                           style: .default) { (actioni) in
        print("Selected C")
    }
    
    actions.append(ac)
}


@IBAction func runAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil,
                                        message: nil,
                                        preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    actions.forEach({
        actionSheet.addAction($0)
    })
    
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true) {
        print("Done")
    }
}
```

The array of actions is created once and not changed. Every time the button is pressed, an `ActionSheet` is created and the unchanged actions are added.
However, the menu will only work the first time. If I recreate the actions they work as expected.
It looks like actions cannot be reused, although I did not see that being documented.

- Edit:

This was resolve here:
[UIAlertController - Action not executed if alert dismissed the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291504/uialertcontroller-action-not-executed-if-alert-dismissed-the-first-time)
By sending a `copy()` of `UIAlertAction`:

```
actions.forEach({
    actionSheet.addAction($0.copy() as! UIAlertAction)
})
```

Question still valid, looks like the handler is not reusable.